# why is the current page title being output?

Tags: custom-post-types, query-posts, sidebar

this is in my sidebar.php file, which is pulled in in the header.php file (is this bad practice?). anyways, the last item in the list is the current page title, despite my query_posts with an args of only the custom post type of newsletters

```
<?php 
  if (function_exists('dynamic_sidebar') && dynamic_sidebar('Sidebar Widget')) : else : ?>
<div id="sidebar" class="newsletters">
  <h2>Newsletters</h2>
  <ul>
  <?php 
    $args = array ('post_type' => 'newsletters');
    query_posts($args);
    if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post();?>
      <li><a href="<?php the_field('pdf');?>"><?php the_title();?></a></li> 
      <?php wp_reset_query(); endwhile; endif; ?>
    </ul>
</div><!--END sidebar -->
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simple answer - because you're using [`query_posts()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/query_posts), which alters the main query.  It almost always produces unintended results, as you're finding out the hard way right now.

Generally, it's best to call the sidebar using `get_sidebar()` instead of `include` (which you probably are, but it's not clear), and I prefer to call it after the main loop has run so I can use a new `WP_Query()` instead.  This will replace the current loop with completely fresh data, and would be my choice of solution.  Replace `query_posts($args)` with `$query = new WP_Query($args)` and you should be good to go.  Normally, I'd say get rid of your `wp_reset_query()` as well, but since you're calling this in the header you have to leave it so it gives you the normal page data for the rest of the page.  This will lead to some overhead, but if you have good caching you shouldn't notice it at all.

## Edit

Example "working" code:

```
<?php 
if (function_exists('dynamic_sidebar') && dynamic_sidebar('Sidebar Widget')) : else : ?>
  <div id="sidebar" class="newsletters">
    <h2>Newsletters</h2>
    <ul>
    <?php 
      $args = array ('post_type' => 'newsletters');
      $query = new WP_Query($args);
      while ( $query->have_posts() ) : $query->the_post();

        $pdf=get_field('pdf');
        echo "<li>";
        echo '<a href="'.$pdf.'">';
        the_title();
        echo "</a></li>";   

      endwhile; wp_reset_postdata(); ?>

    </ul>
</div><!--END sidebar -->
<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: yeah, im pulling the sidebar in with get_sidebar(); but it's in the header

final code below:

Comment: If using `WP_Query()` for the secondary loop, you should omit `wp_reset_query()`, and call `wp_reset_postdata()` instead.